# status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"","path":"/oauth/token"} /feature/HomeOuath

Tags: karate

Feature: oauth test using
nephos-qe-sec.az.staples.com/oauth

Background:

- url 'https://<<>>/oauth/token'

Scenario: oauth flow

- header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
- configure ssl = true
- form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
- request 'client_id=<<>>&client_secret=<<>>'
- method post
- status 200
- def accessToken = response.access_token

Getting 401 error when running from Karate Framework.

Tried with getting the similar error.

- form field client_id = '<<>>'
- form field client_secret = '<<>>'

[401 Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SehPy.png)

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions around StackOverflow, you can try them here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5Dclient_credentials

Comment: Can you please post the curl for the above API so that it can be debug further?

Comment: @BabuSekaran- Thank you. it worked for me. Need to encode as base64  for client_id and client_secret  pass  header Authorization = 'Basic <<encoded client_id:client_secret  >>